# When using SQL within VBA returning Null for value which isnt Null

Tags: excel, vba, odbc

I have an issue where my SQL query is returning Null for a value that isnt Null. I have done some research and found that the Excel driver for the connection does a check on the values in the first n columns and decides a data type. The issue being that the data type changes part way down the data.

I have read that i can change my connection to tell the driver to check all rows of data in the column. Can someone help with this, as i am not sure how to do this

my connection is

```
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & folderName & "ForcastReport.xlsx;" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
    .Open
```

Thank You

Comment: If the data type changes half way down the column, how exactly is Excel supposed to pick which one to use? If you're good with treating everything as text, you can use `IMEX=1`.

Comment: Thanks, I am happy for it to just be considered text, but where would i place the IMEX=1, as i tried it in a few places and couldnt get it to work

Comment: It *should* work anywhere in the connection string. The example on [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/treating-data-as-text/) puts it last though.